# How to call a function within a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want how to call a function within a function.

This is my function:

```
 function TempConvert() {
        var tempVal = prompt('Enter a temperature');
        var newTemp;

        newTemp = (tempVal - 32/1.8 + 273.15);
         alert(newTemp);
        }
```

This where it needs to be called:

```
function iMenu() {
    var choice = prompt("Type in a number for the corresponding option\nOption 1: Temperature Converter\nOption 2: Option 2\nOption 3: Exit");
    if (choice == "1") {

       // TempConverter needs to go here <<----

    } 
      else if (choice == "2") {
        alert('Option2');
    } 
      else {
        alert('Bye');
        return;
    }
}
```

Thanks. I've tried just placing it there but it had no effect.

Comment: http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter3.html

Comment: Could you show how these functions are situated in the whole code? Looks like some sort of scope problem so we'll need to know what function is inside what.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is call the function, like so:

```
if (choice == "1") {
  TempConvert();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TempConvert();
```

is all you need.  The function scope seems to be in-range, so what's your problem?

By the look of your question's **title,** it seems you cannot call a function that is in a function from outside of the function, because of the **scope.**  You can only call functions that are global to your function.

There is only one way I can think of doing this:

Move the function to an array, like `myArray[0] = (TempConvert())` and whenever you want to use it, just execute `myArray[0];`

Comment: Maybe `TempCovert` is local to a different function?

Answer (score 0):

You can call like,

```
 function iMenu() {
     var choice = prompt("Type in a number for the corresponding option\nOption 1: Temperature Converter\nOption 2: Option 2\nOption 3: Exit");
   if (choice == "1") {
       TempConvert(); // added here
    } else if (choice == "2") {
       alert('Option2');
    } else {
        alert('Bye');
       return;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call your function()

```
   function iMenu() {
        var choice = prompt("Type in a number for the corresponding option\nOption 1: Temperature Converter\nOption 2: Option 2\nOption 3: Exit");
        if (choice == "1") {

           TempConvert();

        } 
          else if (choice == "2") {
            alert('Option2');
        } 
          else {
            alert('Bye');
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any issue about scope, here. If the two function are at the same level, just call `TempConvert();` Probably you mispelled it.